# Which is correct representation for function of variable?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, estimation, gaussian

I have a function as
$$E=\int_\Omega -\log\big( p_i(x)\big) dx$$
where $p_i(x)$ is density distribution which estimated by Parzen window method. 
$$p_i(x)=\frac{1}{\Omega_i} \int_{\Omega_i}K_\sigma\big(I(x)-I(y)\big) dy$$
where $\Omega_i$ is the image domain, with 
$$K_\sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(\frac{-z^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$ 
and $\sigma$ is scalar parameter. $I$ is an image $I(x):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, $i$ is given.

So, which ones is correct for left side: $E(\sigma),E(x),E(x,\sigma),E(p_i)$ or other form?

Update: I upload the original equation for better visualization
[image]

Comment: You should correctly define E(.) as a function of all the variables which effect its value. Hence it is $E(\sigma, z, p_i)$ Or may be you want to treat some of them as "parameters" instead of arguments and call it as $E_{\sigma, p_i}(z)$ it really depends on your taste of it ;)

Comment: Thank you. But $\sigma$ is scalar and $z$ is just pixel location.

Comment: Please tighten up your notation. It seems (to me) to be all over the place. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

---

Based on your new explanations, I think the answer is just
$$
E_{u_i}
$$
given that what you're really trying to find a shorthand for is the expression inside the summation sign in (5) of the screenshot. That is:

$$
\min_{U} \left\{ \lambda \sum_{i=1}^N \int_\Omega r_i(\chi, p_i(\chi)) u_i(\chi) d\chi \right\} = \min_{U} \left\{ \lambda \sum_{i=1}^N E_{u_i} \right\}
$$

so that
$$
E_{u_i} = \int_\Omega r_i(\chi, p_i(\chi)) u_i(\chi) d\chi
$$

---

**Original answer below for reference**

As per @Fat32's comment, any of:

- $E(\sigma, z, p_i)$
- $E_{\sigma,p_i}(z)$
- $E(z; \sigma,p_i)$

is acceptable.

But you need to tighten up your notation. What is $x$ vs $z$? How does $\Omega$ relate to them? What is $y$?

Comment: Thank you Peter K. for your answer. Let $I$ is an image, $\Omega$ is the image domain. The $x$ is pixel location. For each pixel $x$, we can approximate the density distribution of the pixel in each region $i$ by using Parzen window method. I called the density distribution as $p_i(x)$. The Parzen window method used $\sigma$ as scalar parameter to estimate the density. Thus, as my knowledge, I think $\sigma$ is tuning parameter, we don't need to put it as variable. $y$ is other pixel in the image, except the pixel $x$. My goal is that formulates the energy $E$ and optimize it.

Comment: Please refer the Eq. (5) in the paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S003132031100197X

Comment: Could you check my comment? Is it clear?

Comment: @user8264 Yes, that is clear. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: So, how can I represent the energy $E$ in term of which variable? I think $\sigma$ is given. $z$ is just denotes for Gaussian function $K(z)$

Comment: @user8264 : I think it's just $E$ or perhaps $E_\sigma$. See my updates.

Comment: I just think it. It may be wrong. Could you see Eq. 5 of my reference paper. It is more clear. For example, if I used Mean square error $(I-c)^2$, then $E$ will be function of $c$ as $E(c)=\sum_{i=1}^N\int_{\Omega}(I(x)-c_i)^2dx$

Comment: I can't read that paper, it's behind a paywall. That function is different from what you have in your question.  I'm going to close the question until you edit it to ask exactly what you need.  It's all over the place and this question in your comment is different from what you ask in the question....  And please include a screenshot of Eq. 5 of the paper.

Comment: I updated it. Or you can see at https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqptd9o999oq0jw/2012_multiphase_ui_good.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38965/discussion-between-peter-k-and-user8264).